# Why does _.some run when there is no iterator function?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

If you using a looping idiom such as `_.some()`, but don't pass in an iterator function something has gone wrong.  Yet, underscore will replace this with the identity function and continue to run.

Why is this: From [underscore](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L204)

```
  var any = _.some = _.any = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    iterator || (iterator = _.identity); // this line?
    var result = false;
    if (obj == null) return result;
    if (nativeSome && obj.some === nativeSome) return obj.some(iterator, context);
    each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
      if (result || (result = iterator.call(context, value, index, list))) return breaker;
    });
    return !!result;
  };
```

Case usage:

```
_.some([0,1,2,3], null);
```

Comment: An identity function is simply `f(x) = x` or `function(x){return x}`

Comment: So what's the question now? Identity functions are common in functional programming. Exceptions are side effects. What would you expect to happen?

Comment: Same thing that happens when you fail to pass a function to the host environment implementation of `some`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because .. why shouldn't it run?

This is an *API design choice* and just making it "return early" (vs applying the identify function as normal) *would alter the behavior*. This is because the identity function effectively passes down the truthy-ness (of false-ness) of the values:

```
_.some([0,undefined,null,""]) // false
_.some([1])                   // true
```

Comment: I've given a use-case and explained that it's by API design choice (of whomever wrote the API). Maybe they liked it.

Comment: @stack_temp Consistent with how *I* think it should behave. I was trying to argue for it being consistent with other operations like `_.map` or `_.filter`, but this is unfortunately not true, so that idea is shot - and would indicate that it shouldn't assume the identity for "consistency" :(

Comment: @stack_temp API design choice :) Both are valid approaches, but once an API is defined changing it can break lots of existing code. Because of no support from map/filter acting similarly, that's the best answer I can offer.

Comment: @stack_temp But it's what it *could* be used for (and I would presume that whomever wrote such function *thought* it was convenient to use/allow such a form without explicitly specifying an identity function). Again, at this point it might simply be the legacy effect of a particular developer's preference. Going through the project history [if such is available way, way back] may lead to further clues, but I'm just accepting it as it is.

Comment: @stack_temp Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Now I wonder how the error-matrix looks like with native map/filter functions ..

Answer (score 2):

> but don't pass in an iterator function something has gone wrong.

Not at all. The `iterator` is an optional argument and, by default, `_.some()` will test the elements of the collection themselves for *truthiness*. This is [demonstrated in the docs](http://underscorejs.org/#some):

```
_.some([null, 0, 'yes', false]);
=> true
```

The `iterator` just allows you to specify your own condition:

```
_.some([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], function (x) { return x > 6; })
=> false
```

Including testing the *truthiness* of a member of the elements:

```
_.some([ { value: 0 }, { value: 1 } ], function (x) { return x.value; });
=> true
```

Comment: @stack_temp Well, it still *iterates*, testing elements as it goes. The difference is just whether it's testing elements or their members. But, part of the design is so that the [native `.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) can be used if available, which expects an iterator and a reasonable default is `_.identity()`.

Comment: I'm not ranting/raving.  Just realized that a lot of library design is  preference.  The host implementation of `some` will throw an error with out an iterator function.  One likes it one way, the other likes it the other.